# tomcat gives 404 when deploying from intellij, no error

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I am deploying maven application to tomcat from intelliJ. I have a big project which has many modules, and they are built into 3 wars.

I have recently started using intellij for this setup. The same thing works on sts with tomcat.

There is no error in any of the application logs, or tomcat/catalina logs.

Following are some of my setup:
[image]

[image]

[image]

The `/webapp` doesn't have anything uploaded to it. Is that the issue?
However there is nothing uploaded into `/webapp` when it is done by sts. I have combed through all the possible logs in /tomcat/logs or /appdata/intellij/../logs. What am i missing?

I am using IntelliJ 2021.1.2 (Ultimate), tomcat 8.5.65, 66 and tried with 9 as well on windows 10.

Comment: Which URL are you trying to open? IntelliJ deploys the `gadplats-web-ui:war exploded` to `http://localhost:8080/gadplats-web-ui_war_exploded/`.

Comment: Ideally it should be `http://localhost:8080/gadplats-web-ui`, but i tried both

Comment: Is there any `context.xml` inside the deploy? Look at the `path` attribute.